# GCD of Table entries

Tags: evaluation, syntax

This question is from a newbie, so please be gentle in thrashing if I'm missing something very basic.

How can I use GCD on a matrix/vector entries stored as Table. For example, if

`mL={{-(1/(32 h)), 27/(32 h), -(27/(32 h)), 1/(32 h)}}`,

how can I find GCD of its entries?

`GCD[mL]` returns

```
{{GCD[-(1/(32 h))], GCD[27/(32 h)], GCD[-(27/(32 h))], GCD[1/(32 h)]}}
```

and `Apply[GCD,mL]` returns

`{GCD[-(1/(32 h))], GCD[27/(32 h)], GCD[-(27/(32 h))], GCD[1/(32 h)]}`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like `GCD @@ Flatten[mL]` I guess.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Or `GCD @@@ mL` avoids the need for `Flatten`

Comment: Hi Lou, Guesswhoitis and BobHanlon,

Thank you for your prompt responses. I've noted the instructions for voting and accepting the answers.

GCD@@Flatten[mL] returns GCD[-(27/(32 h)), -(1/(32 h)), 1/(32 h), 27/(32 h)]
GCD@@@mL returns {GCD[-(27/(32 h)), -(1/(32 h)), 1/(32 h), 27/(32 h)]}

Which is not what I expect. From this example I expect 32h. Note that, in general cases, all the denominators may not be same, and hence, the need for GCD.

Any further help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks. Saku

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you want [`PolynomialGCD`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialGCD.html) instead of [`GCD`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GCD.html):

```
PolynomialGCD @@ Denominator@*Together /@ Flatten[mL]
(*  32 h  *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much MichaelE2. PolynomialGCD did the job. However, using it only on the denominator is not sufficient, it has to act on the whole fraction. For example, for

mLa = {{1/(8 h), -(1/(4 h)), 1/(8 h), -(1/(4 h))}};

PolynomialGCD @@ Denominator[Together /@ Flatten[mLa]]

returns

4 h

whereas

PolynomialGCD @@ Flatten[mLa]

returns the correct value

1/(8 h).

Thanks again for the helpful hint.
Saku